# mod_rewrite removing name of query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have big problem with my urls. I know how to remove index.php form url, but problem is that I don't know to remove that "?act=" from url.

My link now is **http: //localhost/doctrine/public/?act=test** and I want to create it like **http: //localhost/doctrine/public/test**.

My current **.htaccess file placed in *public*** folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I need help how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Before your expression engine rule, you can add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /doctrine/public/?act=$1 [L]
```

To internally rewrite a request like `http: //localhost/doctrine/public/test` to `/doctrine/public/?act=test`. You need to make sure the links in your content look like `/doctrine/public/test` instead of the one with the query string. If there are links outside of your control (like google indexed pages) you can add this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /doctrine/public/?\?act=([^&\ ]+)
Rewrite Rule ^ /doctrine/public/%1? [L,R=301]
```

to point browsers to the URL without the query string.

This unfortunately isn't going to be compatible with your expression engine URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /doctrine/

    RewriteRule ^(public)/([^/]+)/?$ $1/?act=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```